# Space in bottom of site

Tags: javascript, html, css

link: [removed by author]

I have space in bottom of site (~15px).

Firebug and Chrome developer tools shows nothing is there...

Which element is causing this?

Update: I itertively set display:none; and found that #content is the cause. (itself, not childrens). but why?

Comment: It might have something to do with that clear you have at the very end. It's hard to debug these since the browser doesn't tell you where exactly the space is coming from.

Comment: I itertively set display:none; and found that #content is the cause. (itself, not childrens). but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system.base.css
line 245
in rule:

```
.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

change "content" style to:
`content: "";`
(remove point)

Comment: I tried to find your comment to upvote for right solution :)))